# Error mysqli_stmt::bind_param():

Tags: php, mysqli

Instale el programa XAMPP y sale este mensaje de error y hasta el momento no puedo solucionarlo

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match
>   number of parameters in prepared statement in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\server\enciclopedia\index.php on line 29

y el codigo que estoy utilizando es este:

```
$galNumb = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM enciclopedia WHERE status = "1"';
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($galNumb);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $pjInfo['total']);
    if ( ! $stmt->execute()) {
        trigger_error('The query execution failed; MySQL said ('.$stmt->errno.') '.$stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    $col1 = null;
    $stmt->bind_result($col1); // you can bind multiple colums in one function call

    while ($stmt->fetch()) { // for this query, there will only be one row, but it makes for a more complete example
        $echo .= '<div class="enciclopediarow"><a class="title" href="/enciclopedia/review">Review</a><br>'.PHP_EOL;
        $echo .= '<b>'.$col1.'</b> articulos aprovados</div>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    $stmt->close(); // explicitly closing your statements is good practice
```

Especialmente en esta linea `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($galNumb);`

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

**[`bind_param`()](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)** es una parte fundamental de lo que se conoce como *consultas preparadas*. Trabaja junto con `prepare` y sirve para evitar que una consulta en la que intervienen datos del exterior sea enviada a ejecución directamente. Los datos que vienen del exterior podrían ser modificados por usuarios mal intencionados para pasar a ejecución junto con una consulta normal una o más consultas dañinas. Esto es lo que se conoce como **Inyección SQL**.

Precisamente para lo que sirve `bind_param` es para recoger y pasar esos datos para que la base de datos los ejecute, verificando primero que no hay ningún código malicioso en ellos.

El error: *Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement* está indicando que en la instrucción SQL debe haber un parámetro que deberá ser pasado por `bind_param()`, dichos parámetros son representados en la cadena SQL por el signo de interrogación `?`.

Cuando haces `$stmt->bind_param('i', $pjInfo['total']);`, PHP busca el signo `?` en la cadena `$galNumb`, pero no lo encuentra.

Para usar `bind_param()`en tu consulta, debería ser algo más o menos así:

```
$galNumb = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM enciclopedia WHERE status = ?;';
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($galNumb);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $pjInfo['total']);
```

He supuesto que lo que quieres obtener es los datos en los que `status` es igual al dato recibido en `$pjInfo['total']`.

Verás que en la cadena SQL se ha puesto `status = ?`, significa que ese valor será pasado **aparte** usando precisamente `bind_param()`.

De esa manera se evita que cualquier usuario introduzca consultas maliciosas lo cual es muy fácil si envías una consulta tal cual, con la instrucción SQL y los valores.

El tema de la Inyección SQL es un tema amplio, pero que requiere ser conocido, ya que atañe seriamente a la seguridad de los datos.

Te dejo algunos enlaces:

- En Stackoverflow: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php?s=2|1.6808)
- [Inyección SQL en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php)